# How can I get value from a custom field in body of a page, then put it in the meta tags content in header? Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I tried different ways to get my value data in a custom field and put it in the meta tags property in header but no luck.

My site is running based on Wordpress. I created a page to show data from my custom fields. I added a facebook share button to share the content on Facebook.

When I clicked on share button, Facebook only catched Wordpress Meta Tags default meta tags.

I edited open-graph.php, added a condition to make Wordpress to use my custom meta tags only on that page.

The issue is, I cannot or I don't know how to get the data from database and put it in the meta tags. Because the header is loaded before the body, so those meta tags in header are always loaded before the function getting data from database returns the value. Even when I create the tag I need, they are still located in the body, which is not a correct position for Meta tags.

I tried to put my data function directly in the open-graph.php, right below my page condition statement, but it still doesn't work.

Is there anyway to get the data loaded from body and put it in meta tags in header? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up the og meta tags recently in my `header.php` file in this manner:

```
<?php
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $screenshot_url = esc_url( $theme->get_screenshot() );
?>

<?php if ( is_home() ): ?>

<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo get_home_url(''); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo get_bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $screenshot_url; ?>" />

<?php elseif( is_category() ):
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
$cat_desc = (category_description( $cat_id ) != '') ? category_description( $cat_id ) : get_bloginfo('description');
?>

<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo $cat_name; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo $cat_desc; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $screenshot_url; ?>" />

<?php else: ?>

<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" />
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<?php else: ?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $screenshot_url; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can add any conditional you need - for instance to check if you're on a single page, or some certain template.

When I use [facebook share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) I get correct image and info.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing but I had to write 2 functions. 1 getting data for the custom fields in the body and the other one for header. The reason I can't combine them is I use the first function as a short code. I can't recall it into the header.

Comment: Why would you use og meta tags as a shortcode? Just put them straight in the `header.php` and you're set. No need for complicating your life with such simple things...